# Why does my Slack app not work properly when installed by a non-admin?

Tags: slack, slack-api

We are working on a Slack app that doesn't work well when it is installed by a non-admin user. For example, if we invite a user to a channel using `channels.invite` we get a `not_in_channel` error (of course, when the installer user is not in the channel), what doesn't happen when the installer is an admin.

I see each team can configure who can install apps, but I don't see any option to indicate that the app must be installed by an admin user and throw an error if you aren't and admin of the team your are trying to install the app into. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. We need to ask for the `admin` scope.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of asking for the admin scope I strongly recommend to ask for specific scopes (during installation) that the app needs to perform its functionality. e.g. for [`channels.Invite`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.invite) its channels:write.

Then the app also works when installed by a non-admin, provided that the user has the necessary permissions.

To learn more about the permissions system check out the [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes) on the topic.

Comment: Please, read the question. `channels.invite` has a different behavior based on if it is an admin user or not, so what you suggest doesn't work.